# About the open-source project Maate

Tags: mp3

I want to use the open source LAME library to manipulate MP3 files. After carefully read information on main page of [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/links.php), I find the Maate lib maybe more proper to my task and I also want to read the "good description of MP3 frames" from Maate as claimed by LAME.

Unfortunately, I can't find Maate through the link provided by LAME. So what's going on? Is the project Maate still available? If yes, where can I find it? Any suggestion will be highly appriciated. Thank you all in advance.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They moved to sourceforge, see http://maaate.sourceforge.net/ .

The fact that the ancient link in the LAME pages had the name misspelled (or perhaps they changed it halfway the project) didn't help... nor did the fact that they temporarily moved the website to a place that was blocked from archive.org first.